# How do I change an AD users password given his current credentials?

Tags: .net, winapi, active-directory

The function should be straight forward... here's an example of one.  I have another that uses `NetAPIi32.NetUserChangePassword()`.

In both cases, I get this error:

> The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.

What's odd is that I have turned off all password checks in the group policy, and the new password is generated on the fly.  Here's an example: `"eAV*{T(w2?-tr)orRxHvLi@50"`.

My domain is Windows Server 2008, but I spun up a Window 2012 AD, but same result.

The function below is using impersonation, but I've tried it directly using my account and I'm a domain admin, and I get the same password policy error (2245).

```
bool ChangeDomainPassword(string domain, string username, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            // Validate current credentials
            if (context.ValidateCredentials(username, currentPassword))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.SamAccountName, username))
                {
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        // Change the password
                        user.ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword);
                        user.Save();

                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User not found.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid current credentials.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It seems that when you change the password policy, the changes are not applied as expected. Refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/password-policy-changes-not-applied

"password policy error (2245)" You could try to use `NetUserModalsGet function` to query the password policy.

If you want to change the password of an Active Directory account, you could try to use [Set-ADAccountPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: Thank you Jeaninez...the NetUserModalsGet is returning reasonable values:    usrmod0_force_logoff 0xffffffff int
  usrmod0_max_passwd_age 0x00375f00 int
  usrmod0_min_passwd_age 0x00000000 int
  usrmod0_min_passwd_len 0x00000004 int
  usrmod0_password_hist_len 0x00000000 int
What's odd is I CAN successfully change the password once...than I get 2245 if I try again.  Maybe there some sort of requirement on how fast I can change it.